# can not install ember-cli with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, ember-cli

I have completely uninstalled node from my windows machine, deleted all related node and npm folders.

I reinstalled

- node (v0.12.7)
- npm (3.0.0)
- python (2.7.10)

when I install ember-cli, I get:

> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm install -g ember-cli
>
> C:\Program Files\nodejs\ember -> C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\ember-cli\bin\ember
>
> > bufferutil@1.1.0 install C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\bufferutil
> >     node-gyp rebuild
>
> C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\bufferutil>if not
>   defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   rebuild )  else (node  rebuild ) Die Projekte in dieser Projektmappe
>   werden nacheinander erstellt. Um eine parallele Erstellung zu
>   ermöglichen, müssen Sie den Schalter "/m" hinzufügen.   TRACKER :
>   Fehler TRK0005: Fehler beim Suchen von "CL.exe". Das System kann die
>   angegebene Datei nicht finden.
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(355,5):
>   error MSB6006: "CL.exe" wurd e mit dem Code 5 beendet. [C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxp
>   roj] gyp ERR! build error gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1 gyp ERR!
>   stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17) gyp ERR!
>   stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (child_process.js:1074:12) gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600 gyp
>   ERR! command "node" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\bufferutil gyp ERR!
>   node -v v0.12.7 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1 gyp ERR! not ok C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs └── (empty)
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g"
>   "ember-cli" npm ERR! node v0.12.7 npm ERR! npm  v3.0.0 npm ERR! code
>   ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! bufferutil@1.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild` npm ERR! Exit
>   status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the bufferutil@1.1.0 install
>   script 'node-gyp rebuild'. npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with
>   the bufferutil package, npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR! Tell
>   the author that this fails on your system: npm ERR!     node-gyp
>   rebuild npm ERR! You can get their info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls
>   bufferutil npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\WINDOWS\system32\npm-debug.log npm ERR! code 1 PS
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32>

so, I think the main problem here is the CL.exe error, but I have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: I think its due to 'node-gyp',set this environment variable `set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2013` change `2013` to visual studio you have downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Install Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and create a C++ Project to install dev environment with CL.exe.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32584005/742226