# could not install prerender using npm - "Failed to locate: CL.exe"

Tags: node.js, npm, prerender

I've been trying to install `PreRender.Io` on my local machine to test.  I've installed Python 2.7.10.  When I type:

`npm install prerender`

It gives an error:

```
C:\PreRender\node_modules\prerender\node_modules\phantom\node_modules\dnode\node
_modules\weak>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\
node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the
 file specified. [C:\PreRender\node_modules\prerender\node_modules\phantom\node
_modules\dnode\node_modules\weak\build\weakref.vcxproj]


gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` fail
ed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074
:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
```

I couldn't locate CL.exe, and a quick search on Google seems to be some missing Visual C++ compiler. However, I tried installing say VC++ 2008 redistributable x86, but still same problem.

Any idea what could be wrong?  OS is Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Not sure if this is the same issue or not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32424622/installing-ws-with-npm-causes-error-with-node-gyp

Comment: Not really, however I did manage to solve it finally.  I will post an answer about it, just in case someone stumbles upon the same problem

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem, although it was quite strange.  Honestly, I'm not sure which one solved it completely as I've done quite some stuff.  I had installed Visual Studio 2015 on my machine.  Below is a summary of what I've done:

- Installed **Visual C++ Compiler**, from the VS 2015 installation.  By default it was unticked.  I think this is what fixed the issue.
- Added the path where **CL.exe** `(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin)` and **stdlib.h** `(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include)` are located to the **PATH** environment variable.
- Executed the `npm install prerender` from the **`Developer Command Prompt`** in  of Visual Studio 2015, running in **Administrator mode**

Comment: Just installing **Visual C++ Compiler** was enough for me. By the way, you can do it easily right from VS 2015: File -> New Project -> Visual C++ -> Install Visual C++ components (or something similar).

Comment: "Install Visual C++ components" in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition worked for me too.

Comment: Thanks @whylee you saved me :-) To avoid the need of installing it later, user can select "Programing Languages->Visual C++" during the installation. It is on the first screen where there is a lot of checkboxes to check

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going through an Angular JS tutorial and had this issue, but their docs suggest it isn't a problem:

"We often see an npm WARN message after a series of gyp ERR! messages. Ignore them. A package may try to re-compile itself using node-gyp. If the re-compile fails, the package recovers (typically with a pre-built version) and everything works."

https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: only sometimes it doesnt.

Comment: Didn't work when I tried to do npm install when requiring gulp-sass. The package build failed, nothing was in node_modules

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem came after installing a new version of node. npm install would show the error above. Then I got the error above but not for the package PreRender.Io but for gulp-sass, though I believe the problem has the same root. To solve it, I installed the previous version of node I'd been using (6.9.5) and then I used nvm to manage node versions as described here: https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-multiple-versions-node-nvm/

Switching to the previous version of node using nvm meant I could do npm install without having to install a large SDK I wasn't going to end up using.