# Failed to locate: "CL.exe" during npm install via terminal in Visual Studio Code

Tags: npm-install

I've installed visual studio code for Windows. 
Also, installed node (v 10.0.0).

Typing "npm install" in the integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code, starts installing but ends with an error:
TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified.

I've tried to follow the suggestions here:
[could not install prerender using npm - "Failed to locate: CL.exe"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239445/could-not-install-prerender-using-npm-failed-to-locate-cl-exe)

but without any success.

**Error:**

verbose stack Error: rabin-bindings@1.7.4 install: `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`

verbose stack Exit status 1

gyp ERR! cwd ..\node_modules\rabin-bindings

gyp ERR! node -v v10.0.0

gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2

gyp ERR! not ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been more helpful to answer accurately if you had provided error stacktrace.

Anyway I faced similar problem and in my case, I was using node-gyp v3.6.0, which added VS2017 support, so that's a good start.

I was getting `"KeyError: '2017'"` which suggested node-gyp wasn't detecting the version of Visual Studio. So I forced it using below cmmand, and it did the trick:

```
npm config set msvs_version 2017
```

Comment: You rock! Thank you!

Comment: no problem @DimaK , just one advice to add error stacktrace in you future questions so that it gets answered to the point and as early as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @curiousManish , I will make sure to include it next time in my question.
Also, I've edited my current question. I could not find the "KeyError: '2017'" you've mentioned in my stacktrace, but the error is all about node-gyp.